# Pointer to object in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, new-operator

I saw the below code in `Stackoverflow.com`.
I was looking for the same code, bacuse I have a doubt.
If we will see the below code
`CRectangle r1, *r2;`
`r2= new CRectangle;`
1. Why are we doing `new CRectangle`? What actually we are trying to do?

1. One of colleague told me, 
   when we write the code we make,
   `CRectangle *r2 = 0;`,

Then we `initialize` with some other value or address. I really got confused. Please help me.

```
using namespace std; 
class CRectangle
{
    int width, height;  
public:    
    void set_values (int, int);  
    int area (void) {return (width * height);
    } 
}; 
void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) 
{    
    width = a;   
    height = b;
} 
int main () 
{   
    CRectangle r1, *r2;    
    r2= new CRectangle;    
    r1.set_values (1,2);  
    r2->set_values (3,4);   
    cout << "r1.area(): " << r1.area() << endl;    
    cout << "r2->area(): " << r2->area() << endl;  
    cout << "(*r2).area(): " << (*r2).area() << endl;  
    delete r2;    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry Rasmi Ranjan Nayak, your english is quite confusing. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CRectangle r1, *r2; r2= new CRectangle;

`r1` is the object. `r2` is the pointer to the object.

```
CRectangle *r2 = 0;
```

Pointer contains the address of the object. If the pointer has not initialized, it can have any value (that we don't know). So, we initialize `0` so that we know our pointer has value `0`. We can use that value to avoid double initializing or some memory error.

When we are about to assign the object to the pointer, what we usually do is_

```
if (r2 == 0)
    r2 = new CRectangle;
else
    std::cout << "Pointer is not empty or invalid" << std::endl;
```

Comment: :- I think your explanation really answers my doubt. I was bit confused with `r2 = new CRectangle` but @JonathanWood answered the same. Thanks A Lot

Answer (score 1):

In your example `r1` has type of `CRectangle` class, but `r2` has type of pointer to CRectangle class. The pointer is just address in global memory ([heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management)). In order to allocate and mark memory as `CRectangle` object we need use `new`.

Please, read the details in [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
CRectangle r1, *r2;    
r2= new CRectangle;
```

This code declares a `CRectangle` object (`r1`), and a pointer to a `CRectangle` object, which doesn't yet point to anything (`r2`). Both variables are allocated on the stack.

The second line allocates memory for a new `CRectangle` object (from the heap), calls any constructor for that class, and then returns the address and assigns it to `r2`. So `r2` then points to a `CRectangle` object.

Setting `r2` to 0 or `NULL` is simply a standard way to indicate that the pointer doesn't actually point to anything.

Comment: Thnaks for making me understand.